# Pandoc managed Markdown to LaTeX to PDF workflow fails to port simple pipe_tables

Tags: pandoc, markdown

I'd like to setup a simple workflow allowing me to type document segments in their own files using Markdown, then convert them to LaTeX using a common library such as `pandoc`, before finally collating all my document segments into a main file that would be output as PDF.

I've created a table that looks like the below in Markdown:

```
 $x$    |   $F(x)$         
--------|------------------
 $0$    |  $\frac{2}{8}$    
 $1$    |  $0$              
 $2$    |  $\frac{1}{2}$    
 $3$    |  $2\frac{1}{2}$   
 $4$    |  $6\frac{3}{4}$   
 $5$    |  $14$
```

This renders pleasantly enough in the markdown preview window I've got setup in Atom, but after I've converted this document using the commandline:

```
pandoc -f markdown+tex_math_dollars+pipe_tables table.md -o table.tex
```

The above construction is converted to:

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule\addlinespace
$x$ & $F(x)$
\\\addlinespace
\midrule\endhead
$0$ & $\frac{2}{8}$
\\\addlinespace
$1$ & $0$
\\\addlinespace
$2$ & $\frac{1}{2}$
\\\addlinespace
$3$ & $2\frac{1}{2}$
\\\addlinespace
$4$ & $6\frac{3}{4}$
\\\addlinespace
$5$ & $14$
\\\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
```

Which when piped through:

```
pandoc table.tex -o table.pdf
```

Doesn't resolve into a table, the initial line particularly looks fishy.

I can manually re-jig this to something like:

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
$x$ & $F(x)$ \\
\hline
$0$ & $\frac{2}{8}$ \\
$1$ & $0$ \\
$2$ & $\frac{1}{2}$ \\
$3$ & $2\frac{1}{2}$ \\
$4$ & $6\frac{3}{4}$ \\
$5$ & $14$ \\
\end{tabular}
```

Which is the result I want, but it takes time and I'd really like to be able to achieve this result directly from markup without human intervention.

Comment: Is there a special reason for going from md -> latex -> pdf ? Pandoc is able to produce a pdf directly by using LaTex as the backend. Your MWE **does** work, I just simply process it with:
`pandoc -S pipetable.md -o pipetable.pdf`. 
I am using pandoc 1.15.2 on Kubuntu 14.04

Comment: I think I might like to skip the middle step, but at some point in the future, I'd like to group/compile multiple sections/chapters into a final document, and was under the impression that I'd only be able to have access to that kind of facility using latex \input or \include commands.

Comment: That's not necessary as you can pipe several .md files together.
`pandoc -s -S mermaid.md pipetable.md -o together.pdf`
You can also customize the appearance of your PDF by tweaking the LaTex template with 
`pandoc -D latex > latex.default`

Comment: OK cool, I've been able to try the md to pdf method, and find that works perfectly. And if I can go straight from md to pdf, then maybe I don't need the latex stepping-stone.

Comment: So it looks like this works for the immediate issue of generating a functioning pdf, but it would be good to get the latex middle-step, just so I can apply styling to one or more blocks of latex'd text. 

Though, I guess I can achieve much of this by updating the latex.default template as you mention...let me try that out...

Answer (score 2):

My answer: always re-test with the latest release of Pandoc if you run into any problems.

I'm currently using *Pandoc v2.1*, which is not even the newest one (that would be *Pandoc v2.5*). For your example table in Markdown, my 2.1 version gives me as LaTeX output:

```
pandoc          \
   -f markdown+tex_math_dollars+pipe_tables \
   -t latex     \
   -o -         \
      md-table.md 

\begin{longtable}[]{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule
\(x\) & \(F(x)\)\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
\(0\) & \(\frac{2}{8}\)\tabularnewline
\(1\) & \(0\)\tabularnewline
\(2\) & \(\frac{1}{2}\)\tabularnewline
\(3\) & \(2\frac{1}{2}\)\tabularnewline
\(4\) & \(6\frac{3}{4}\)\tabularnewline
\(5\) & \(14\)\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
```

The resulting LaTeX converts to PDF just fine, as well as a "direct" output of PDF works with the original Markdown. There isn't even a need to specify the Pandoc extensions (*`+tex_math_dollars+pipe_tables`*) as you did:

```
pandoc              \
     md-table.md    \
    -f markdown     \
    -o md-table.pdf \
    -V geometry:"margin=10pt, paperwidth=80pt, paperheight=120pt"

magick convert -density 300 md-table.{pdf,jpg}
```

(I'm using ImageMagick to create the JPEG for visualizing the resulting output in this answer, below.)

[image]